# jQuery on change within jQuery replaceWith

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I got this idea that whenever a person chose an option from a select it shows something else like this:

```
$('#secbutt').click(function(){
    $('#secnow').replaceWith('<div id="sec" style="width:100px;margin:0px;"><select id="technical" name="sec"><option value="Systems">Systems</option><option value="Technical">Technical</option><option value="Network">Network</option></select></div>');
    $('#secbutt').hide();
});
```

that's from another function I did which is working, so if a person chose Technical this should appear:

```html
 <div id="technow" style="width:100px;margin:0px;">
          <select name="tech">
               <option>Jen</option>
               <option id="tech">Jeff</option>
               <option>Joms</option>
          </select>
    </div>
```

and this will hide:

```
<span id="itnow">Something is inside</span>
```

This is the jQuery function I did:

```
$("#technical").change(function(){
var val = $(this).val();
  if(val === "Technical"){
    $("#technow").show();
    $("#itnow").hide();
    //$(".showPendings").show();
  }else{
    $("#technow").hide();
    $("#itnow").show();
    //$(".showPendings").hide();
  }

});
```

Am I missing something? Thanks!

Comment: What isn't working for you?

Comment: the change() function,

Comment: It's inside the replaceWith function.. @chriscozzens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to change your event handler to the following :

```
$("body").on('change', "#technical",function(){
var val = $(this).val();
  if(val === "Technical"){
    $("#technow").show();
    $("#itnow").hide();
    //$(".showPendings").show();
  }else{
    $("#technow").hide();
    $("#itnow").show();
    //$(".showPendings").hide();
  }

});
```

Comment: No, tried that it doesn't work as well.. I'm think it's because the selector I have is inside a jQuery function?

Comment: When clicking on #secbutt, does the desired html appear?  If you inspect it? Is it just not changing properly, or is the problem stemming from the replacewith function itself?

Comment: the replaceWith function works, the select with id="technical" appears, just the one with the change function is not working..

Comment: Ahhh I believe you may have to call the event handler on #secnow instead of #technical because that is the element that is actually changing.

Comment: @TheTruth Cheers Brother!

Comment: @TheTruth I'm glad I could help. The problem was that the element is dynamically added to the page. In those cases you'll need to add the event listener using something like `$("parent").on("event", "element selector", function(){....})`

Comment: Updated answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

`$("#technical").change(function(){`

Change above line of code by this,

`$(document).off('change', "#technical").on('change', "#technical",function(){`